# Kotlin Type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was expected

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am trying to get the Maximum number between two numbers in Kotlin & I keep getting Type mismatch error. I tried using Int?.toInt() It didn't work.

I also tried to use Int!! as the double exclamation for None Null values, It didn't work too.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){

    val nums = arrayOf(8, 5, 6, 8, 9)
    var sorted = arrayOfNulls<Int>(nums.size)

    // manually set 2 values
    sorted[0] = nums[0]
    sorted[1] = nums[1]

    for(i in 1 until nums.size-1){
        val value = sorted[i - 1]
        val max = maxOf(value!!, nums[i]) // This line throws Null pointer exception: error: type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was expected
        // do something with max
    }

    println(sorted)
}
```

Comment: It throws an NPE because `sorted` is full of nulls (except for the two first elements, and you're using `!!`, which means: trust me, it's not null, and throw an NPE if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`arrayOfNulls()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html) function is declared as

```
fun <reified T> arrayOfNulls(size: Int): Array<T?>
```

Thus any item of `sorted` might be null. So if you want to properly use it as null, just do a normal null check `value != null` before using it.

Instead of using nulls, you could also use `Int.MIN_VALUE` as initialization value.

```
val sorted = Array(nums.size) { MIN_VALUE }
```