# Type mismatch error when adding a map value to a variable (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

1. I want to add a value from a MutableMap to the total, but I keep getting *Type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was expected* error and I don't know how to fix this issue
2. I tried calling the value as Int `menu[item].toInt()` and setting logic in the if statement that checks that the item is indeed Int, but nothing helped.

Please, see the code below

```
fun main() {
    
    val order = Order()
    order.placeOrder("Noodles")

}


 val menu: MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf("Noodles" to 10,
                              "Vegetables Chef's Choice" to 5,
                              )

class Order {
    var total = 0

    fun placeOrder(vararg orderedItems: String) {
        for (item in orderedItems) {
            if (item in menu) {
                total += menu[item]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Kotin Type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but Int was expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664688/kotin-type-mismatch-inferred-type-is-int-but-int-was-expected). I'd recommend you do some reading on [Kotlin null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html). Also searching for the error message on SO before you post would be nice.

Comment: It’s not a duplicate of that one because this question is about why `map.get` returns a nullable and putting values into a map.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `menu[item]` is a shorthand for `menu.get(item)` which is defined as `Map<K, out V>.get(key: K): V?`.

In case no element with the specified key is found in the map, `null` is returned.

You may fix this by providing a default value, in case the returned value is null, e.g.:

```kotlin
total += menu[item] ?: 0
```

`Map<K, out V>` also provides alternatives, which provide `Int` instead of `Int?`.
You may use `getValue(key: K): V`, which throws an `NoSuchElementException`, when there is no element with the given key.
Alternatively, you can utilize `getOrElse(key: K, defaultValue: () -> V): V` or `getOrDefault(key: K, defaultValue: V): V` which both provide a fallback value instead of null.

Examples for the different alternatives below:

```kotlin
total += menu.getValue(item)
total += menu.getOrElse(item) { 0 }
total += menu.getOrDefault(item, 0)
```